# Connection the Android device to adb without drivers

Tags: android, adb

I have a device of local company. The support says that they have no imformation about drivers of my device. Windows 7 automatically found drivers and it can see sd-card of device. But ADB can't see the one. Is there any idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you have an adb supported device, you can first turn the USB debugging on and if windows wont recognize the device you need to install an ADB driver which is provided either by Google USB driver package which comes with android sdk or you can download the adb driver installer from http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

For connecting device in window 7 we require USB driver of your android device.
But If you are using Linux operating system in this case no need of USB driver.

Answer (score -1):

install [moborobo](http://www.moborobo.com/) in your pc and connect the phone. moborobo will install a suitable driver to your phone. it Worked with my local phone.

Comment: It was not help for my device

Answer (score -1):

try this way.

first kill adb server by below command on command prompt.

`adb kill-server`

Now again start adb server with following command on command prommpt.

`adb start-server`

Then try to see you device using below commnad

`adb devices`